# Java: Stacked (layered) maps behind a Map interface?

Tags: java, dictionary, stacked, layered

I need a Map impl which would consist of stacked maps, which I could `push()` and `pop()`, and the values would be "added" or "removed" if they belong to the map being pushed/popped. And the values would be searched top/bottom (or optionally bottom/top).

Is there an existing impl in JDK or elsewhere?

Example:

- Stack

  - map4

    - foo => aaa
    - bar => 45
  - map3

    - bar => 22
  - map2

    - foo => ccc
    - baz => uuu
  - map1

For this, `get("baz")` would return `"uuu"`, `get("foo")` would return `"aaa"`, `size()` would return `3` etc.
It's something like JavaScript's prototypal inheritance.

There's [one impl](http://www.programmers-friend.org/apidoc/org/pf/util/StackedMap.html)
I'm wishing for some more sophisticated impl, which wouldn't really go through all layers every time I call any method. Read methods are going to be more often than push()/pop(), so there could be some pre-computation during that.

Comment: And how would you create the "outer maps" here?

Comment: There is no builtin structure in the JDK like that, but it'd be pretty easy to write an implementation of yours using, say, a `LinkedList<Map<K, V>>`

Comment: You can use a `LinkedBlockingDeque<Map<K, V>>` if you need the stack to be thread-safe

Comment: Compare with Properties,  which can have another Properties map as default values.

Answer (score 0):

You can have Stack as a wrapper. Have a Map<'String, Map> ( String here is for the name of the map). Expose push and pop as API. Interesting part of your question is, defining push and pop? How would the signature of these method actually look like? Actually, not very clear is to what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

So, there is no such builtin structure in the JDK, but it can be implemented using a `LinkedList` containing `Map`s.

`LinkedList` implements all three of `List`, `Queue` and `Deque`, maybe it's a little overkill, but ohwell...

A sample code would be as follows; however, the `Map` interface is not really obeyed (curious how you'd do `.equals()` and `.hashCode()` here? Not even talking about `.clear()`):

```
public final class StackedMap<K, V>
    implements Map<K, V>
{
    private final Map<K, V> NO_MAP = new HashMap<K, V>();
    private final LinkedList<Map<K, V>> maps = new LinkedList<>();

    private Map<K, V> currentMap = NO_MAP;

    public void push(Map<K, V> map)
    {
        maps.push(map);
        currentMap = map;
    }

    public Map<K, V> pop()
    {
        return currentMap = maps.pop();
    }

    @Override
    public V get(K key)
    {
        V ret;

        for (final Map<K, V> map: maps)
            if ((ret = map.get(key)) != null)
                break;
        return ret;
    }

    // etc
}
```

Untested etc.

Comment: Regarding `LinkedList` being overkill, Java has a `Stack` class, but its documentation says "A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is provided by the Deque interface and its implementations, which should be used in preference to this class"

Comment: @fge how about having has-a relationship than is-a? I was thinking it would be a better thing to do considering the question

Comment: Sure I can write it myself, but I'm wishing for some more sophisticated impl, which wouldn't really go through all layers every time I call any method. Read methods are going to be more often than push()/pop(), so there could be some pre-computation durint that.